# Import a 3d object on threejs with JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender, maya

i'm trying to use a very simple 3dobject i made with Maya in my threejs project using jsonloader but i have a few problems.
The ojbect is composed by a few different material (Lambert and Phong) and different colors.
To create the .json file i use Maya to create a .obj then Blender to make the .json and everything seems fine but when i try to import it loading HIS material i can't even load the model, instead if i use a random material while loading i'm able to correctly load the model.

```
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("http://localhost:8000/object/planev2.json", function 
            (mygeo,mymat){
            var mat =  mymat[0];
            mymesh  = new THREE.Mesh(mygeo,mat);
            mymesh.scale.set(50,50,50); 
            scene.add( mymesh );
    });
```

TL:TR - Is possible to load directly from a .json an object made by different materials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                        color: 0xdddddd,
                        specular: 0x222222,
                        shininess: 35,
                        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "tex/map1.jpg" ),
                        specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "tex/map2.jpg" ),
                        normalMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "tex/map3.jpg" ),
                        normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 ),
                        morphTargets: true
                    } );

                    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( );

                    loader.load( "mesh.json", function( geometry ) {

                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        mesh.name = "male";

                        scene.add(mesh);

                    });

                    loader.onLoadComplete = function () {

                        console.log("Loading is complete!");

                    }
```